# How to access an array from a certain point every loop?

Tags: vba, excel

**Question detail**

My code below stores the results from a calculation in array `funds()` and repeats that process for the selected range. By the end there will be a one dimensional array with 170 values. I need to access the array from a certain point every loop to fill the new row with different values.

**Problem in detail**

The core problem I am having is printing that array to a range on the workbook which is made up of 10 rows by 17 columns.

I managed to get it to go down a row once the "for each cell in selected range" loop exits, but now it fills the new row with the same initial array values!

Here is the current output:

[image: Output]

**What have i tried?**

- I have tried the Redim but get overwhelmed by the length of examples.
- I have tried manual copy and paste but feel like that is cheating...
- I have researched how to delete elements through the process of copying..

Overall I am sure there is a simple way that everyone knows how to use! but what is it?

**In a nutshell...**

> Every loop remove the initial 17 values, then print the next 17 array values to new row in range. Repeat 10 times.

**The code**

```
Option Explicit
Public funds(0 To 170) As Variant

Sub cumulativeperformance()

    Dim selectedrange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim value1 As Double
    Dim Value2 As Long
    Dim i, x, d, c As Integer
    Dim total(0 To 170) As Double

    'Copy the table to report
    Worksheets("Data").Range("C3:T13").Copy
    Sheets("Report").Range("B39").PasteSpecial
    Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:T13").Copy
    Sheets("Report").Range("A39").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Repeat 9 times
    c = 39
    For d = 0 To 9

        c = c + 1
        Set selectedrange = Worksheets("Report").Range(Cells(c, 3), Cells(c, 19))
        For Each cell In selectedrange

            value1 = cell.Value

            'get the value of cell to the left of current cell
            Value2 = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

            'get the difference to previous month
            value1 = value1 / Value2 - 1

            'assign result + 1 to array
            total(x) = value1 + 1

            'If initial fund slot is 0, then store first result of calculation in that slot
            If i = 0 Then
                funds(i) = total(0) - 1
            ElseIf i > 0 Then
                'Do calculation on remaining values and store in fund array
                funds(i) = (funds(i - 1) + 1) * total(i) - 1
            End If

            'MsgBox "cumulative performance: " & funds(I) & " Cell address: " & cell.Address
            i = i + 1
            x = x + 1

        Next

        'Write from one dimensional Array To The worksheet
        Dim Destination As Range
        Dim j As Integer

        Set Destination = Range(Cells(c, 3), Cells(c, 3)) 'starts at
        Set Destination = Destination.Resize(1, 17) 'UBound(funds))
        Destination.Value = funds

        'MsgBox "Hi there"

    Next d

    'one-off commands in here
    Range("C40:S49").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Call portfoliomay

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of creating a 1D array, create a 2D array, eg:`Dim Funds(1 to 10, 1 to 17)`.  Fill in the array as if you were filling in the Range, with the first dimension the rows, and the second the columns.  Then do  `Set Destination = Destination.Resize(ubound(Funds,1),ubound(Funds,2)) : Destination.Value = Funds`

Comment: So .. is your funds array filled with the correctly updated values? You're just looking at updating the new cells?

Comment: Thanks guys, your answers and editing helped a lot. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination range and the source array should have the same dimensions to be able to assign the values correctly, as commented by Ron Rosenfeld. This is possible by either using a 1-dimension array to reuse 10 times for just one row at a time `array(columns)`, or a 2-dimensions array for the full destination range (10x17) `array(rows, columns)`.

### Method #1: 1-dimension array

Use a 1-dimension array of 17 values, for a row by row operation, one row at a time. Initially declare the array as a dynamic array `Dim funds() ...`, so you'll be able to easily reset it. Then set its zero based length `ReDim funds(16) ...` at the beginning of each `For d = 0 To 9` iteration. The rest of your code will stay the same. With this method your original destination assignment should work as expected `Destination.Value = funds` (or with an equivalent shorter statement `Cells(c, 3).Resize(1, 17) = funds`).

### Method #2: 2-dimensions array

You can declare funds as a zero based 2-dimensions array `Dim funds(9, 16) ...`. But then there is no straight forward way to put the data in row by row. **The destination assignment will be to the whole range at once** `Cells(40, 3).Resize(10, 17) = funds` **after your calculation loops end**. You will also need to adjust the `funds` directives to indicate the row `funds(d, i) = ...`. This may be the most efficient way (performance wise) to put in the data in your sheet, as putting data in cells is relatively time consuming.

*To do it row by row with a 2-dimensions array you'll have to use a workaround like the ones described here [return an entire row of a multidimensional array in VBA to a one dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173622/return-an-entire-row-of-a-multidimensional-array-in-vba-to-a-one-dimensional-arr).

### Other adjustments

You will need to adjust your `total` array to have the same dimensions and directives as the `funds`, or adjust `i` and `x` calculations. To adjust `i` and `x` and leave `total` as is, add `i = 0` at the beginning of your `For d` iteration, and use only `total(x)`.

Comment: Thanks dePatinkin, just woke up so will have a go at this now :)

Comment: I tried the small changes you described in Method #1. However i get "Subscript out of range" and when i click debug it points to this line "funds(i) = (funds(i - 1) + 1) * total(i) - 1". My changes as mentioned were 1. added Dim funds() 2. added ReDim funds(16) at beginning of for D loop.

Comment: As I stated it needs to be funds(i) = (funds(i - 1) + 1) * total(**x**) - 1, but I'm not sure that is your problem. You should debug it for the values of x and i, and the bounds of the arrays.

Comment: Thanks! that works. Now need to debug why the first Column C stays as 0.95%.... on every row. To illustrate, in the picture i previously attached above, the rows update only from column 28/2/15. Need to make it from 31/1/15

Comment: Fixed, if statement total needs to be total(x) too.... can i donate to you dePatinkin? like enough for u to get a coffee :)

Comment: Not enough reputation! once i get i will definitely come back

Answer (score 1):

**edited** after OP's confirmation his goal is optimizing code (see at the end)

I'm adding a different "flavor" of array/ranges use and showing some possible code enhancements

1. `Variant` variable as array

   there's no need to `Dim` or `Redim` any array, just declare ita as a pure Variant variable and fill it with the range values that will host the final results

   some thing like

   ```
   funds = repRng.Value
   ```

   where `repRng` is the `Range` of the "Report" sheet that you want to fill with `funds` array itself
2. reduce variables

   there's no need for a total array at all. just use a simple `Double` variable
3. `Dim` appropriately

   ```
   Dim i, x, d, c As Integer
   ```

   would result in declaring `i`, `x` and `d` variables as of `Variant` type and only `c` as of `Integer` type

   to have all those variables declared as integer you must type:

   ```
   Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, d As Integer, c As Integer
   ```

   but we'll use much less of them
4. reduce code

   since you're assigning

   ```
   value1 = value1 / Value2 - 1
   ```

   and then

   ```
   total(x) = value1 + 1
   ```

   you could merge those two statements into the single

   ```
   total(x) = value1 / Value2
   ```

   which, for what above said, we'll change to:

   ```
   total = value1 / Value2
   ```
5. copy/paste

   these statements:

   ```
   Worksheets("Data").Range("C3:T13").Copy
   Sheets("Report").Range("B39").PasteSpecial
   Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:T13").Copy
   Sheets("Report").Range("A39").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   ```

   actually do the same as:

   ```
   Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:T13").Copy
   Sheets("Report").Range("A39").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   ```

   which can also be written as:

   ```
   With Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:T13")
       Sheets("Report").Range("A39").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
   End With
   ```

   this approach both reduces time (not an issue for such little a range) and doesn't use the clipboard (which at least you'd take care releasing with `Application.CutCopyMode = False`)

   for what above said, this statement will be used to initialize `repRng` `Range` variable, too

   ```
   With Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:T13")
       Set repRng = Sheets("Report").Range("A39").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) '<--| define the range where to paste data
       repRng.Value = .Value '<--|  paste data
   End With
   ```
6. Reduce variables (part2)

   your `d` variable is used only for iterating through rows you just previously copied and pasted, but you're using hard coded values for its span and then making it relative to another hard coded reference row index (`c = 39`)

   you'd better exploit consistente reference to the range you're actually dealing with, like (pseudo code)

   ```
   Dim oneRow As Range

   For Each oneRow In repRng.Rows '<--| loop through rows of your relevant data range
       For Each cell In oneRow.Cells '<--| loop through cells of the current data range row

           'code

       Next cell
   Next row
   ```

   where `repRng` is a `Range` object referencing relevant cells of sheet "Report" you want to loop through

---

The final outcome will be the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Public funds As Variant '<--| declare the simple Variant variable that will be "turned" into an array as long as we'll initialize it to a "Range" values

Sub cumulativeperformance()

    Dim cell As Range, repRng As Range, oneRow As Range
    Dim value1 As Double, total As Double
    Dim value2 As Long
    Dim iRow As Long, jCol As Long '<--| better use "Long" instead of "Integer" when dealing with numbers that cope with Excel rows indexs

    'Copy table values to report
    With Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:T13")
        Set repRng = Sheets("Report").Range("A39").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) '<--| define the range where to paste data
        repRng.Value = .Value '<--|  paste data
    End With

    With repRng
        Set repRng = .Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 2) '<--| redefine the relevant data range to loop through
    End With

    With repRng '<--| assume your relevant data range as reference
        funds = .Value '<--| have funds array properly dimensioned by filling it with relevant data pasted values: they'll be rewritten in following loops

        For Each oneRow In .Rows '<--| loop through rows of your relevant data range

            iRow = iRow + 1 '<--| update array row counter
            jCol = 1 '<--|for each new row restart array column counter
            For Each cell In oneRow.Cells '<--| loop through cells of the current data range row

                value1 = cell.Value  '<--|get the value of current cell
                value2 = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value  '<--|get the value of cell to the left of current cell
                total = value1 / value2 '<--|evaluate the ratio

                If jCol = 1 Then
                    funds(iRow, jCol) = total - 1 '<--| If initial fund slot is 1, then store first result of calculation in that slot
                Else
                    funds(iRow, jCol) = (funds(iRow, jCol - 1) + 1) * total - 1 '<--| Do calculation on remaining values and store in fundS array
                End If

                jCol = jCol + 1 'update array column counter
            Next cell

        Next oneRow

        .Value = funds '<--| fill your relevant data range with funds values
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End With

'    Call portfoliomay

End Sub
```

---

further optimization would avoid the `If jCol = 1 Then` check for every row, since it's not up to some unknown condition:  we know for sure that every new row will start with a column index 1

so, for every row, we can

1. act on its initial column:

   ```
   funds(iRow, 1) = GetTotal(oneRow.Cells(1, 1)) - 1 'evaluate funds current row first slot (column)
   ```

   relying on a specific `GetTotal()` function

   ```
   Function GetTotal(cell As Range) As Double
       Dim value1 As Double
       Dim value2 As Long

       value1 = cell.Value  '<--|get the value of current cell
       value2 = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value  '<--|get the value of cell to the left of current cell
       GetTotal = value1 / value2 '<--|evaluate the ratio
   End Function
   ```

   where we collected the code to calculate `total` value "attached" to a single `cell`
2. do calculation for subsequent columns

   ```
       jCol = 2 '<--|for each new row restart array column counter
       For Each cell In Range(oneRow.Cells(1, 2), oneRow.Cells(1, oneRow.Cells.Count)) '<--| evaluate funds current row remaining slots
           funds(iRow, jCol) = (funds(iRow, jCol - 1) + 1) * GetTotal(cell) - 1
           jCol = jCol + 1 'update array column counter
       Next cell
   ```

   exploiting the same `GetTotal()` function

Finally the updated code would be:

```
Option Explicit

Public funds As Variant '<--| declare the simple Variant variable that will be "turned" into an array as long as we'll initialize it to a "Range" values

Sub cumulativeperformance()

    Dim cell As Range, repRng As Range, oneRow As Range
    Dim iRow As Long, jCol As Long '<--| better use "Long" instead of "Integer" when dealing with numbers that cope with Excel rows indexs

    'Copy table values to report
    With Worksheets("Data").Range("B3:T13")
        Set repRng = Sheets("Report").Range("A39").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) '<--| define the range where to paste data
        repRng.Value = .Value '<--|  paste data
    End With

    With repRng
        Set repRng = .Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 2) '<--| redefine the relevant data range to loop through
    End With

    With repRng '<--| assume your relevant data range as reference
        funds = .Value '<--| have funds array properly dimensioned by filling it with relevant data pasted values: they'll be rewritten in following loops

        For Each oneRow In .Rows '<--| loop through rows of your relevant data range

            iRow = iRow + 1 '<--| update array row counter

            funds(iRow, 1) = GetTotal(oneRow.Cells(1, 1)) - 1 'evaluate funds current row first slot (column)
            jCol = 2 '<--|for each new row restart array column counter
            For Each cell In Range(oneRow.Cells(1, 2), oneRow.Cells(1, oneRow.Cells.Count)) '<--| evaluate funds current row remaining slots
                funds(iRow, jCol) = (funds(iRow, jCol - 1) + 1) * GetTotal(cell) - 1
                jCol = jCol + 1 'update array column counter
            Next cell

        Next oneRow

        .Value = funds '<--| fill your relevant data range with funds values
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End With

'    Call portfoliomay

End Sub

Function GetTotal(cell As Range) As Double
    Dim value1 As Double
    Dim value2 As Long

    value1 = cell.Value  '<--|get the value of current cell
    value2 = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value  '<--|get the value of cell to the left of current cell
    GetTotal = value1 / value2 '<--|evaluate the ratio
End Function
```

some final(?) notes:

A. `Public` variables

these are used to share variables among different subs/function across different modules

but it's usually a bad practice using them, being preferable put those variables in subs/function parameters to carry them along where needed

with the code as in the question, there is no other sub/function using `funds`, so it better move its declaration into cumulativeperformance():

```
Option Explicit

Sub cumulativeperformance()

    Dim funds As Variant '<--| declare the simple Variant variable that will be "turned" into an array as long as we'll initialize it to a "Range" values
    Dim cell As Range, repRng As Range, oneRow As Range
```

B. simplify GetTotal()

```
it can be simplified to

    Function GetTotal(cell As Range) As Double
        With cell
            GetTotal = .Value / .Offset(0, -1).Value '<--|evaluate the ratio
        End With
    End Function

taking advantage of the `With cell` statement and referring to it
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for taking the time to do the above. I was planning to optimize the code and no will do with the tips given. Thanks!

Comment: I used the following to make my code much better too [Styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366588/what-does-a-good-programmers-code-look-like)